# glassfish-4 + spring jndi name java:comp/env/jdbc/

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, glassfish-4

In spring web-app we have a bean

```
<bean id="test" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
   <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/testRes"/>
</bean>
```

in glassfish4 config this source declared as jdbc/testRes

it's all work but
if we write jndi name like this

```
    <bean id="test" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
       <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/testRes"/>
    </bean>
```

it stops working.

this web app have many declares jndi name like java:comp/env/jdbc/testRes and we need to maintain compatibility in tomcat7 and glassfish4.

how can we configure a mapping of this names ?

we have found a solution but it doesn't work

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>java:comp/env/jdbc/testRes</res-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>jdbc/testRes</jndi-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Probably you found solution but if anyone else is having same issue...

Try to add to resource-ref this line:

```
<lookup-name>jdbc/testRes</lookup-name>
```

so it looks like this:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>java:comp/env/jdbc/testRes</res-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>jdbc/testRes</jndi-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <lookup-name>jdbc/testRes</lookup-name>
</resource-ref>
```